# importing from excel's string based DATE results in "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Tags: c#, excel, datetime

Experts need help to solve this crazy issue :) and same query has been floating around the internet for a long time also.

To being with, we have excel file and the user who enter the date into this excel file sometimes do not following the good practice. For example.

Scenario 1: (dd/mm/yyyy)

```
+---- Date ----+
+09/12/2014    +
+09/12/2014    +
```

Scenario 2: (dd/mm/yyyy) [but additional digit would be missing either in date or month area]

```
+---- Date ----+
+9/12/2014     +
+9/12/2014     +
```

Scenario 2A: (dd/mm/yyyy)

```
+---- Date ----+
+9/1/2014      +
+9/1/2014      +
```

Scenario 3: (mm/dd/yyyy) [exact like Scenario 2 & 2A]

```
+---- Date ----+
+12/9/2014     +
+12/9/2014     +
```

Scenario 3A: (mm/dd/yyyy)

```
+---- Date ----+
+1/9/2014      +
+1/9/2014      +
```

Scenario 4: (dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy)

```
+---- Date ----+
+9/1/2014      +
+9/1/2014      +
```

Now, the real issue is

1. We would not be able to identify the actual format entered in excel file, i.e. if its mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy
2. Though we have now set the guidelines for excel file format, we still worried about "Human Error", which we would like to take care in our code as much as possible.
3. So far we haven't yet got any issues with respect to year part of the date. All the time we are getting 4 digits in year, but still we would like to have this sorted out as much as possible.

What we have using at present is the following code after doing tremendous research

```
Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.ParseExact(item["Excel_Date_Column_Name"].ToString(), "dd/mm/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("mm/dd/yyyy"))
```

But as said earlier, if the input date format does not match to the reading format we get error for example,

```
This format works
-----------------
Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.ParseExact("13/12/2014", "dd/mm/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("mm/dd/yyyy"))

This format will not work
-------------------------
Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.ParseExact("13/12/2014", "mm/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("mm/dd/yyyy"))
```

We have also come across of using the character **'** in excel file.

```
+---- Date ----+
+'9/1/2014     +
+'9/1/2014     +
```

Is there any method to solve this issue and try to make a generic parser which will eliminate these above mentioned concerns would be really helpful to us and anyone facing this similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

This will likely be due to the date column in Excel having a Date format with a locale that doesn't match the locale that your program is running as.

I am not sure if you can detect the locale of the given cell as I'm not aware of what library you are using to read in the spreadsheet.

The best approach would be to use the `yyyy-MM-dd` date format, as there will be no ambiguity as to day/month in the date string.

Comment: I do understand its a challenge, but currently we are putting the rules to person involved in generating these XLS file. Hope fully it should not be an issue. But in any case we would like to takecare of this issue at our end, by providing some AI (Artificial Intelligence) feature which will do verification on input date we receive from XLS. Yes we can consider to use yyyy-MM-dd but again we are not sure about vendors would agree with this change due to their company policy.